# meaning of iid in multivariate CLT

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

when we say that sequence of $X_n$ is iid. Do we require that, say we have a random vector as follows
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_n \\ y_n \end{pmatrix}, $$
$x_n$ and $y_n$ to be iid, too? or can they be any random variable -- different distribution and dependent.

Comment: A little confused as to what you're asking. Are you asking whether the $x_n$ is iid from $y_n$ (when they are part of the same component vector, i.e., when $n$ is equal for $x_n$ and $y_n$)? Pretty sure the answer to that specific question is a no.

Comment: Indeed the distribution of every $(x_n,y_n)$ can be anything (but the same for every $n$).